# Rails with Octopus gem. How to create db's defined in shards.yml with rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sharding, octopus

I need to configure my app to use multiple shards, and even multiple db adapters. I have noticed that all rake commands like `rake db:migrate` are working, and have consequence on shards defined in shards.yml, except `rake db:create`. 
It will be a real pain to create all this manually.
How can I make it work?

My database.yml (I have defined here, only my master shard)

```
development:
  adapter:  postgresql
  host:     localhost
  encoding: unicode
  database: db_workload_master_development
  pool:     5
  username: 
  password: 

production:
  ......
```

My shards.yml

```
octopus:
  environments:
    - production
    - development
  development:
    shards:
      mysql:
        host: localhost
        adapter: mysql2
        database: db_workload_mysql_shard_development
      sqlite:
        host: localhost
        adapter: sqlite3
        database: db_workload_sqlite_shard_development
      pg:
        host: localhost
        adapter: postgresql
        database: db_workload_pg_shard_development
        pool:     5
        username: 
        password: 
  production:
    ....
```

Only db's from database.yml are created with rake-task `rake db:create`.

Comment: Same problem here... I dont understand how to create the shard databases... Should I create them by hand? wtf

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating your own rake task that will read the shards.yml and create the db's as appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

I think the Octopus gem using shards rake task like db

Try `rake shards:create`